# google maps javascript api - get location on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i need to get (somehow) the longitude/latitude of a user once they click on the google map i provide them with.

i need to get this information to my method in c# so i can save it in the database.

--

use case:

1. user accesses the page with a google maps on it
2. user clicks on his/her location
3. onclick gets the information and passes it to a c# method saveLocation(latitude, longitude)

is there a tutorial or info how to do this? i found some that do this with javascript but i need this info to get to the server side method.

thnx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the information in javascript and send the information to server side through the ajax call.

```
 GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) {
          if (latlng) {
            marker = new GMarker(latlng, {draggable:true});
                var latlng = marker.getLatLng();
                var lat = latlng.lat();
                var lng = latlng.lng();
              //send these lat and lng to server side save location method through ajax

          }
            map.addOverlay(marker);
          });
```

Comment: syntax error, need to rewrite to this way:   GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) {
            if (latlng) {
              marker = new GMarker(latlng, {draggable:true});
                  var latlng = marker.getLatLng();
                  var lat = latlng.lat();
                  var lng = latlng.lng();
                //send these lat and lng to server side save location method through ajax

            }
          map.addOverlay(marker);
  });